# Amplitude modulation with diode

Tags: modulation, amplitude-modulation

I was studying about amplitude modulation and I found this circuit on the internet.

- Does anyone know why that ground is needed?
- Is the first part(three resistors) an adding circuit?
- Does the diode apply the square law?

[image: circuit]

Comment: The diode only allowed the Positive voltages onto the resonator. If moderate bandwidth is implemented, the carrier plus sidebands will be replicated by the stored energy, and the + and the - voltages restored. So yes, seems like the diode non-linearity is needed. Given diodes do not provide squarelaw region (some FETs go), the "modulation" is mostly just distortion, to be filtered by the moderate bandwidth resonator.

Comment: Try simulating it. Not only will you learn to use a simulator (very important) but you'll gain intimate knowledge and far more than a short answer can provide.

Comment: Thanks guys I searched and found that the resistor in red has a high resistance value. Is it to gain power? And in the material I found something about the non-linear response of the diode can be approached by an e ^ x so I thought it was the squarelaw